# Run Docker in Windows 10

Tags: docker

I'm trying install and runing docker on Windows 10, but I'm stuck in this error,

I'm following these steps

- Install Virtual Box
- Turn off the Hyper-V
- Restart PC
- docker-machine create box
- Turn on the Hyper-V
- Restart PC
- docker-machine start box

**Error**

`This is a known VirtualBox bug. Let's try to recover anyway...
Error setting up host only network on machine start: The host-only adapter we just created is not visible. This is a well known VirtualBox bug. You might want to uninstall it and reinstall at least version 5.0.12 that is is supposed to fix this issue`

I read this [github issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30239) e also [this one](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/636) , but still with the same error.

Someone can help me ?

I'm using VirtualBox version 5.2.8-121009-Win

**Some commands and results**

**docker ps**

```
error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.37/containers/json: open //./pipe/docker_engine: O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
```

**docker-machine ls**

```
NAME   ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL   SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
box    -        virtualbox   Stopped                 Unknown
```

**docker-machine start box**

```
This is a known VirtualBox bug. Let's try to recover anyway...
Error setting up host only network on machine start: The host-only adapter we just created is not visible. This is a well known VirtualBox bug. You might want to uninstall it and reinstall at least version 5.0.12 that is is supposed to fix this issue
```

Comment: Can I ask why you are using Virtual Box, but still have HyperV enabled? As you have HyperV enabled, why not just use the default Docker/Windows 10 Linux host that runs in HyperV?

Comment: @MichaelLloydLeemlk I'm beginner with docker, and I'm just following some tutorials. I disabled the HyperV and try the `docker-machine start box` (I've created that with `docker-machine create box`) but still got the same error

Comment: It sounds like you are following an old tutorial. Enable Hyper-V, install the latest version of Docker for Windows and it should all Just Work. Docker for Windows will create you a VM in Hyper-V running Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments above it sounds like you are either following an old tutorial (before [Docker for Windows](https://www.docker.com/docker-windows)) or following a tutorial for devices which do not meet the requirements for Docker for Windows (i.e. for Windows 10 Home). Given you are turning off Hyper-V I'm going to assume you are using Windows 10 Pro.

The latest version of Docker for Windows does not use the docker-machine command, and will instead create a VM for you in Hyper-V 'behind the scenes'. You should be able to get away with just [installing Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#download-docker-for-windows)

Comment: Unable to create: The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual switch with name "DockerNAT".
at New-Switch, <No file>: line 123
   at Docker.Backend.HyperV.RunScript(String action, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.Start(Settings settings)
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<Register>b__0(Object[] parameters)

Comment: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/324

I've had this issue before, I had to uninstall Docker, go into the HyperV app and remove everything (VMs, switches, etc) then reinstall.